# RHEL6 httpd Root CA configuration

Tags: ssl, configuration, ssl-certificate, httpd, rhel6

I'm setting up SSL on a RHEL6 box and I'm having problems finding information about configuring the Root CAs.

I've got four files:

- `cert.crt` - My SSL certificate
- `my_key.key` - The key used to request/generate the certificate
- `CorpDomain.cer` - File given to me by my company, this is an ASCII Test file
- `CorpServices.cer` - File given to me by my company, this is a binary file

In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` I have the following:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my_key.key
#SSLCertificateChainFile
#SSLCACertificateFile
```

The email I got from my company when they issued my certificate said:

> It's important that you install the related certificate chains.  For
>   the certificate you requested you need two Root CAs:
>
> CorpDomain.cer
>
> CorpServices.cer
>
> If you don't know how to install the chain, you will find instructions in your platforms documentation.

Now, I think I need to concatenate `CorpDomain.cer` and `CorpServices.cer`, however `CorpServices.cer` is a binary file, and httpd doesn't seem to be happy with it on its own...
I've looked at the documentation, and it seems to suggest I need to know a bit more about the certificates I have, however, the above email is all the information I have and the department that issued it refuse to offer help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely `CorpDomain.cer` and `CorpServices.cer` are binary DER encoded CA certificate files, which you can easily convert to the base 64 PEM format with:

```
openssl x509 -in CorpDomain.cer -inform der -outform pem -out CorpDomain.pem
```

Afterwards you can concatenate both PEM files to form the `SSLCertificateChainfile CorpChain.pem` you include in the apache configuration.

```
cat CorpDomain.pem CorpServices.pem > CorpChain.pem
```

Comment: I'm not sure that both of them are though - I've updated my question as it was a little ambiguous.  `CorpDomain.cer` is an ASCII text file...

Comment: The one that's ASCII text is probably already done, so you should only need to convert the binary encoded one.  Then cat the two plaintexts together.

Comment: Just to be pedantic,the PEM CA certificates are not plain text, they are base 64 (ASCII) encoded :)

Comment: Yep, you were correct.  Seems to work just fine now :D  Thank you very much!